# There is English mingled with Portuguese in the Portuguese Stack Exchange site

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, portuguese-stackoverflow

In the [Portugues Stack Overflow tour page](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) there is English intermingled with the Portuguese for certain words and phrases:

[image]

That is, it uses the phrase "professional and enthusiast programmers" instead of "programadores profissionais e entusiastas" and "programming" instead of "programação".

The [help page](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) is even worse: all the help pages are completely in English.

[image]

Comment: That’s funny; when I go there, all I get is a “Log-in” page that seems to be broken. Do I have to set something in my browser options (e.g., to add Portuguese to my list of languages) to get the site even to work?

Comment: You have to be a member of the private beta @Scott...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Really? I'm able to access it, but I didn't commit to the proposal. How did I become a member of the private beta without commiting or being invited to it?

Comment: Hmmm, no idea. If I access the page it definitely tells me about the private beta though.

Comment: @ben no, public beta is accessible to anyone.

Comment: I can't remember exactly after this length of time but something weird did happen with this in the past @Shadow. This is probably out of date now though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tour has been updated.

Translation updates aren't instant, so English may be occasionally shown in various places as we release new features or fix issues in existing copy until the next translation drop.

Comment: You mean translation runs on a separate "layer" after every code change?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Translation is done by humans. We contract a company for it. We send them text in English, they send us back Portuguese.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the info!

Answer (score -4):

The phenomenon of code switching is perfectly natural and valid for a site which extensively uses both.  This naturally happens in virtually all setting in which multiple languages are constantly in contact and is fine for this site.

Comment: I think though, that there are two problems in this particular case. 1) There *are* valid Portuguese phrases that can accurately represent the concepts, and 2) The whole goal of the site is to be welcoming to Portuguese speakers and as a courtesy you would at least expect translated help (I presume it's not translated yet and I'm not criticizing the lack of translation, I'm only saying that the answer is not "yeah, it happens and is acceptable" - more like "it's a work in progress").